# Connecting SQL SERVER in C#.net on networked server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

I have an existing application build in C#.net, using SQL SERVER 2005, earlier application and SQL was on same machine, but now I need to connect SQL which is on server and is networked to the machine on which application is installed.
So can any one tell me how to connect SQL to application , and what changes need to be made in connection string.

Thanks 
EDIT : I am a bit new to c#.net.
 currently my connection string is : public SqlConnection con = new sqlConnection("server=.;database=Database1;integrated security=sspi); so if I just put this will it directly connect to the SQL which is on other computer ?

Comment: See http://www.connectionstrings.com/ for sample connection strings.  The correct one for you will depend on your specific setup.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on whether you are using SQL Server authentication

**Standard Security** (SQL Server authentication)

> Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;

or to connect to a specific instance on the server

> Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
>   Password=myPassword;

**Trusted Connection**

> Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;

http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005

Comment: I am a bit new to c# and SQL,
so, @Eric J can you tell me what do you mean by instance 
and currently my connection string is :
public SqlConnection con = new sqlConnection("server=.;database=Database1;integrated security=sspi);
so if I just put this will it directly connect to the SQL which is on other computer ?

Answer (score 0):

Server=.;

Means you were connecting to a default instance of sql2005 on the same machine.

Since 2005 SQL Server has allowed instances.

So you could have MyMachine/MyLiveDBMSInstance and MyMachine/MyTestDBMSInstance.

Basically as though you'd installed sql server twice. Default (ie unnamed) instances were a backwards compatibility measure, so DBAs didn't have to go around explaining what an instance was to mere programmers. :)

You would have connected to them with Server = MyMachine\MyLiveDBMSInstance or perhaps 
Server = .\MyInstance  dot being this localhost basically.

So you can't use . any more, you need tthe name of the machine, and if it's using a named instance, you'll need that as well.

i.e Server = RemoteMachine or Server = RemoteMachine\InstanceName

Course all this assumes the machine with the dbms is on is set up correctly and the windows user running the application has been allowed access.